# Simular clique sem chamar diretamente a função

Tags: javascript

Usando javascript puro, eu queria clicar num botão e dispara os eventos dele, mas o importante é que não quero chamar a função diretamente.
Até agora tentei isso:

```
var send = document.getElementsByName("send");
window.addEventListener("keyup", function( e ){
    if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13){
        send.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    }
});
```

Eu procurei em vários artigos, mas preciso do equivalente a jQuery `element.click();`, mas os artigos só ensinam a chamar a função diretamente interligada ao elemento.

```
<button name="send" onclick="alert('foo')">Enviar</button>
```

Usando javascript puro, como eu eu foço um clique nesse botão sem ser diretamente ou chamar a função que esta no `onclick`

Comment: Tente detalhar melhor seu objetivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código me parece estar correto, só tem uma coisa errada `getElementsByName` retorna uma lista de itens (equivalente a `array`), o certo seria:

```
var send = document.getElementsByName("send");
window.addEventListener("keyup", function( e ){
    if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13){
        send[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));//send[0] pega o primeiro button que achar
    }
});
```

Comment: Fantástico. O fato é que eu havia me esquecido de que getElementsByName retorna um array de elemento, por isso a necessidade de usar o índice 0. Consegui corrigir de duas formas, colocando o send[0] ou buscando o send com getElementeById. Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Tem o [`aply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

[Resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/906565/3497987)

```
var elem = document.getElementById("linkid");
if (typeof elem.onclick == "function") {
    elem.onclick.apply(elem);
}
```