# Como simular um evento de click, sem o usuário clicar realmente no elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de simular o onClick em algum elemento, porém sem o usuário clicar no elemento, por exemplo, o usuário aperta Enter e o evento disparado é o mesmo que clicar em determinado elemento da page, existe como fazer isso? Pode ser em JS puro ou JQuery

Comment: [**Simular clique sem chamar diretamente a função**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59664)